# imagecreatefromstring giving Notice with specific file

Tags: php, php-gd

here's the code:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $full_name . '.jpg');
 $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('uploads/' . $full_name . '.jpg'));
 //...
```

user can upload a file (`photo`) , there's no problem with uploading it 
but the second line **sometimes** give's me this:

> Notice: imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9 in E:\xampp\htdocs... on line 20

it doesn't fail the process but it's a *Notice* anyway...

what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's a JPEG-file you're trying to process?

Comment: yes, I've checked `$_FILES['photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'`

Comment: If that is code you exactly copied, `$_FILE` should be `$_FILES`.

Comment: no, it's not :) (Edited)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to my error handling. I'd set up an error handler so my call to

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('uploads/' . $full_name . '.jpg'));
```

wasn't suppressing errors.

By modifying my error handler with:

```
if (error_reporting() === 0){ return false; }
```